# Function design decisions

Tags: c++

I am developing a library of some utility functions in C++. I have a doubt regarding the function signatures in that library. If a function takes some parameters and returns a value, should the variable into which the result of that function is stored also be passed as a parameter to that function? How should I handle the error conditions and return values for errors?

Comment: You have tagged this as both "C++" and "C".  Please pick one, as the answer may be very different for each one.

Comment: It is a matter of choice and perspective so follow the coding guidelines laid out by your organization.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth : It would be great if you could tell me the differences in each of the languages, thanks.

Comment: That would be *far* too much to cover in a comment...

Comment: @RakeshK When in doubt follow boost. Boost usually has two signatures for it's functions, one that has an error code reference parameter, and one that throws an exception. It would be trivial to code the exception throwing one in terms of the error code returning one.

Comment: @EthanSteinberg: for performance reasons, and especially when the Zero Cost Exception scheme is used by compilers (which is what gcc and clang use on x86 platforms) I would instead code the error returning one in terms of the exceptions throwing one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For C++ you should return the result and handle errors with exceptions.

```
int calc_with_error() {
    throw yourExceptionClass("Message");
}
int calc() {
    return 5;
}
int main() {
    int tmp=calc();
    cout << calc;
}
```

But the result then is copied from the function to the calling context. With primitive datatypes this is the fastest possible way. But when you have complex datastructures, it can be faster to pass a reference to a result parameter - although it's not as clean code as the solution above, An example would be:

```
void calc(vector<int> &result) {
    result.clean();
    result.add(5);
}
int main() {
    vector<int> tmp;
    calc(tmp);
    //Do something with the vector
}
```

Comment: Don't forget about the Return Value Optimization: copies of return values are often optimized out.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options, and it's largely a matter of preference.
One thing you should do is, in most cases, keep outputs and errors separate.
It's usually good to return success/error as the return value, and return data in an output parameter, passed by reference.

Don't do these:
1. Use "magic values" as an error indication.
2. Use global variables to return the data.

Comment: This is true for C, less so for C++.

Comment: @RakeshK: Exceptions don't appear in the function signature.

Answer (score 1):

People often tell me to not return error values, because this is not the very best practice. The best is to you throw exceptions, this is best handled than error codes. Also, output parameters are good, I use them most for big data, for simple returns, the return value should be of good use.

To show you, of course, this is not so good in design:

```
void checkSomething(bool& output)
{
    output = doCheckages();
}
```

that is much better

```
bool checkSomething()
{
    return doCheckages();
}
```

but if youre handling a large class/structure, and you know that you dont want to have lots of instance of it, may be better to pass it as a output param.